# Как правильно организовать связь между компонентами в бд?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, laravel

В данный момент переписываю одно приложение, так как прошлая схема БД была ужасной.

**Есть два модуля:**

- Блог
- Компании

Блоги могут имееть как компании так и пользователи. Также каждая компания относиться к определеному пользователю.

**Частые операции:**

- Выборка блогов пользователя и компаний который ему принадлежат.
- Проверка кому принадлежит статья блога, если это компания то кто ее
  владелец.

**Требования:**

- Маштабируемость Удобство использования

Технологии:

- MariDB
- laravel

[image: Структура бд]
В данный момент избавился от связующих таблиц, добавив полиморфную связь в таблице Блог. Но кажеться что схема не верна, помогите добиться "идеальной" структуры

Comment: Полиморфных связей лучше избегать. Вам нужно убрать связь blogs-company и blogs-users, сделать промежуточную таблицу autors которую соединить с blogs (1к1), users (1к1) и company (1к1), например. Либо объединить таблицы users и сompany

Comment: @ArchDemon, сделайте Ваш комментарий в форме ответа